# Mounting a squashfs filesystem in read-write

Tags: mount, squashfs, read-write

I have a Clonezilla installation on a USB stick and I'd like to make some modifications to the operating system. Specifically, I'd like to insert a runnable script into `/usr/sbin` to make it easy to run my own backup command to make backups less painful.

The main filesystem lives under `/live/filesystem.squashfs` on the USB FAT-32 partition.

How can I mount this read/write on my Linux machine in order to be able to add/remove/change files? I'm running an Ubuntu 12.04 derivative.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This assumes that you are *root* and that `squashfs-tools` is installed on your system:

---

Copy `filesystem.squashfs` to some empty dir, e.g.:

```
cp /path/to/filesystem.squashfs /path/to/workdir
cd /path/to/workdir
```

Unpack the file then move it somewhere else (so you still have it as a backup):

```
unsquashfs filesystem.squashfs
mv filesystem.squashfs /path/to/backup/
```

Go in `squashfs-root`, add/modify as per your taste then recreate<sup>1</sup> `filesystem.squashfs`:

```
cd /path/to/workdir
mksquashfs squashfs-root filesystem.squashfs
```

Copy the newly created `filesystem.squashfs` over the existing one on your USB drive, e.g.:

```
cp filesystem.squashfs /mnt/clonezilla/live/
```

then reboot and use your LIVE USB.

---

<sup>1: Consult the manual for additional options that you can pass, like `-b 4M -comp lz4` or `-comp xz -Xbcj x86` etc</sup>

Comment: This works great, but unfortunately, I get a message for all the root directories telling me `Source directory entry bin already used! - trying bin_1`. Sure enough, in my output filesystem, I have a `/bin` and a `/bin_1`, rather than merging the folder. Any ideas? If I run with `-noappend,` the filesystem simply doesn't work.

Comment: @TKKocheran - I'm not getting any of those errors here after adding a custom script in `/usr/bin` and repacking with `mksquashfs`. USB drive boots fine and I can use my script from the live session. Make sure you no longer have the old `filesystem.squashfs` in the same directory with your modified `squashfs-root` before running `mksquashfs`.

Comment: @Naftuli: You seem to have skipped the "mv ... backup/" step.

Comment: Does this work not under (fake)root? Just from extracting I get the error `create_inode: could not create character device squashfs-root/dev/audio, because you're not superuser!`

Comment: @Wilf - you cannot create device files (`squashfs-root/dev/*`) as regular user, you need root privileges.

Comment: Why did you specify all those flags to `mksquashfs`? I read the [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/squashfs-tools/mksquashfs.1.en.html) but are they needed?

Comment: If I `unsquash` my debian live iso on an Ubuntu 20 system I get errors for symlinks and also for some files. Is this due to my host system not permitting the symlink or is this a problem with `unsquash`? The errors are like `create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/xinput-zh_TW, because Operation not permitted`

Answer (score 14):

If your system supports some uion-filesystem, such as **aufs** or **overlayfs**, you don't have to extract your original squashfs file.

For example the **overlayfs** is used( a kernel option to enable it):
You can mount your squashfs.file to */fm* or somewhere else first.
Prepare a writable filesystem with 2 directories in it, say */to* and */temp*.
prepare another writable directory */fin* for the merged results.
Mount them together as an overlayfs to your system ---

```
mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=/fm,upperdir=/to,workdir=/temp overlay /fin
```

Now you can add/modify files in */fin*.  Once everything done, you can mksquashfs */fin* to a new squashfs file,

```
mksquashfs /fin newfile; umount /fin
```

, then clear/unmount all the other used directories as you will.

The **squashfs** and some **unionfs** are commonly used for a **live-cd**.

Comment: If you delete a file from the mounted /fin, will it be removed from the final squashfs you create?

Comment: @localhost, it should not be included. BTW, `fin` is not mounted, it is `overlayfs` that is mounted at `fin`.

Answer (score 9):

[Here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/SquashFS-HOWTO/), I found an other answer:

```
bash# mount dir.sqsh /mnt/dir -t squashfs -o loop
```

Comment: The above command will mount it read-only, which is better than not mounting it at all; alas, not a complete answer to the question at hand.

Comment: I agree that it is not a complete answer. Together with https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/377269/27328 you can build an answer where you do not need to unpack your file system to modify it - less space, less time.

Comment: Simplest method, worked on CentOS 7

Comment: would be good if you added needed steps to make is writable. For some (like me) seeing "together with" means lots of additional work to do (though might be beneficial for learning).

Answer (score 2):

Note: question written in 2013, now is 2021, I assume `overlayfs` (one of `unionfs` filesystems) is supported. This answer is basically merge of two other answers with some things written explicitly, proficient Linux users might see something as obvious (like using `sudo`), but not everybody is at that level, I've understood some things along the way and writing complete (IMO) instructions. Texts after `#` are comments, no need to copy them, on my system `bash` safely ignores them.

```
cd somefolder # some folder, no need for much free space, enough for modified data only
mkdir fm # for mounting original
mkdir to # for upper unionfs layers
mkdir temp # some overlayfs technical folder
mkdir fin # resulting folders/files would be there

sudo mount /full_path/filesystem.squashfs fm -t squashfs -o loop
sudo mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=fm,upperdir=to,workdir=temp overlay fin
```

Now can modify/add/delete files/folders in either "to" or "fin" folders.
Changes to them are "mirrored".
To undo deletion of original file delete "deleted" file from "to" with `sudo rm path/file`.
After done with modifications to make new `squashfs` file in full_path folder, needs to be free space there:

```
sudo mksquashfs fin /full_path/filesystem.squashfs
```

When you don't need your working files anymore:

```
sudo umount fin
sudo umount fm
sudo rm -R fm fin temp to
```

P.S. After change to `quashfs` I wanted to recreate `iso` file of modern distro which support both legacy and EFI boot. Why some options to below `genisoimage` command are critical, I don't know, for me I was trial-and-error way. Boots both EFI and legacy, however start of iso is different: starts `33 ed 90` instead of `45 52 08`, e.g. mjg59.dreamwidth.org/11285.html hints me Apple support is missing.

```
mkdir iso,efi

sudo losetup --partscan --show --find original.iso

# if output of previous loop0
sudo mount /dev/loop0p1 iso
sudo mount /dev/loop0p2 efi # not necessary, just to see contents

sudo mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=iso,upperdir=to,workdir=temp overlay fin
```

Replace what is needed in `fin`. Initially did `sudo dd if=/dev/loop0p2 fin/EFI/BOOT/usb.efi` to make image for efi, then found out it is already present in `grub` folder. If one takes available efi image, than `losetup+mount /dev/loop` steps can be replaced by simpler `sudo mount original.iso iso`

```
sudo genisoimage -lJr -o new.iso -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 --boot-info-table -eltorito-alt-boot -e boot/grub/efi.img -no-emul-boot fin

sudo isohybrid --uefi new.iso
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script based on Martian2020's answer that can do this using overlayfs.  I am creating an fstab file so that it is easy to restore using `mount -a --fstab`

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -eu
src=$(realpath $1)
tgt_dir=$(dirname $(realpath ${2-$src}))
tmp=${2-$(dirname $src)/$(basename --suffix=.squashfs $src)}
tgt_name=$(basename $tmp)
target=$tgt_dir/$tgt_name
workdir=$tgt_dir/.$tgt_name-work
lowerdir=$tgt_dir/.$tgt_name-lower
upperdir=$tgt_dir/.$tgt_name-upper
fstab=$target/fstab
echo $src $target $workdir $lowerdir $upperdir
set -x
mkdir $workdir
mkdir $upperdir
mkdir $lowerdir
mkdir $target
cat > $fstab <<EOT
# This fstab can be used with "sudo mount --fstab $fstab -a" or appended to
# /etc/fstab
$src $lowerdir squashfs loop,ro 0 0
overlay $target overlay lowerdir=$lowerdir,upperdir=$upperdir,workdir=$workdir 0 0
EOT
sudo mount --fstab $fstab -a
```

Answer (score 0):

Using overlayfs as shown is the best way to have pseudo "squashfs rw" ;
It requires however to run on > 4.x kernel (or ubuntu >14.x trusty ).

An alternative solution when one is sitting on older live cd without any overlayfs/aufs/unionfs is to make use of squashfs'own capabilities

Important: **Without unsquashfs, so this can be done on low storage system**

Example:

Modify squashfs's "usr" directory

```shell
mount squashfs_file /mnt    # 1
cp -a /mnt/usr $HOME        # 2  Modify whatever $HOME/usr as needed
mksquashfs /mnt new_squashfs_file -wildcards -e usr   # 3
mksquashfs $HOME/usr new_squashfs_file -keep-as-directory # 4
umount /mnt  # 5  Cleanup
```

Line 3 builds temporarily squashfsfile excluding olddir_usr
Line 4 appends modified-usr-dir into new_squashfsfile

See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375191/append-to-sub-directory-inside-squashfs-file?rq=1) append squashfs