# Merging preexisting source folders in mksquashfs

Tags: clonezilla, squashfs

In [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80312/5614) on a previous question, I found out how to modify files in a squashfs filesystem:

```
# unsquash the filesystem to a local directory
sudo cp /media/clonezilla/live/filesystem.squashfs ./
sudo unsquashfs filesystem.squashfs
# now, insert my own script which I want as part of the distribution
sudo cp ~/autobackup squashfs-root/usr/sbin/
# now, resquash the filesystem to be able to use it
sudo mksquashfs squashfs-root filesystem.squashfs -b 1024k -comp xz -Xbcj x86 -e boot
```

However, on that last line, I run into some problems making the filesystem:

```
Source directory entry bin already used! - trying bin_1
Source directory entry dev already used! - trying dev_1
Source directory entry etc already used! - trying etc_1
Source directory entry home already used! - trying home_1
Source directory entry initrd.img already used! - trying initrd.img_1
Source directory entry lib already used! - trying lib_1
Source directory entry lib64 already used! - trying lib64_1
Source directory entry media already used! - trying media_1
Source directory entry mnt already used! - trying mnt_1
Source directory entry opt already used! - trying opt_1
Source directory entry proc already used! - trying proc_1
Source directory entry root already used! - trying root_1
Source directory entry run already used! - trying run_1
Source directory entry sbin already used! - trying sbin_1
Source directory entry selinux already used! - trying selinux_1
Source directory entry srv already used! - trying srv_1
Source directory entry sys already used! - trying sys_1
Source directory entry tmp already used! - trying tmp_1
Source directory entry usr already used! - trying usr_1
Source directory entry var already used! - trying var_1
Source directory entry vmlinuz already used! - trying vmlinuz_1
```

Essentially, since it's overwriting an existing squashfs filesystem, instead of merging duplicate files, it creates new folders and files in the root of the filesystem named `bin_1`, `etc_1`, `var_1`, `tmp_1`, etc.

Obviously, this is not desired. Is there a way that I can force it to merge the directories? I have attempted to run it with `-noappend`, but that breaks the Clonezilla install and I can't get into the Clonezilla wizard. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in my other answer you have to move the old `filesystem.squashfs` to another location (or rename it) before repacking your modified `squashfs-root` into a new `filesystem.squashfs`:

```
mv filesystem.squashfs /path/to/backup/
```

or

```
mv filesystem.squashfs filesystem.squashfs.old
```

then:

```
mksquashfs squashfs-root filesystem.squashfs -b 1024k -comp xz -Xbcj x86 -e boot
```