# How can I chroot into a live filesystem.squashfs Linux distribution?

Tags: chroot, live-usb, squashfs

I would like to **chroot** into a *Live USB* Linux distro, if such thing is possible. I don't know if there is a generic method, so I will detail my specific test.
I am testing **Kali Linux v1.0.5 Live USB** created from Windows using *"Universal USB Installer"*.
This is the root of the pendrive:

```
23/12/2013  01:12 am    <DIR>          uui
05/09/2013  09:50 am    <DIR>          .disk
05/09/2013  09:51 am                25 autorun.inf
05/09/2013  09:47 am    <DIR>          dists
05/09/2013  09:46 am    <DIR>          firmware
05/09/2013  09:51 am           159.629 g2ldr
05/09/2013  09:51 am             8.192 g2ldr.mbr
05/09/2013  09:50 am    <DIR>          install
05/09/2013  09:51 am    <DIR>          isolinux
05/09/2013  09:49 am    <DIR>          live
05/09/2013  09:52 am            42.803 md5sum.txt
05/09/2013  09:47 am    <DIR>          pool
05/09/2013  09:51 am           366.350 setup.exe
05/09/2013  09:50 am    <DIR>          tools
05/09/2013  09:51 am               223 win32-loader.ini
11/01/2013  05:55 pm            49.070 Uni-USB-Installer-Copying.txt
24/11/2013  10:22 pm            18.233 Uni-USB-Installer-Readme.txt
04/04/2012  08:42 pm            18.092 license.txt
01/01/2014  09:23 pm    <DIR>          Instalac
               9 archivos        662.617 bytes
              10 dirs   1.486.944.256 bytes libres
```

...and, as long as I suppose this is the important part:

```
 Directorio de k:\live

23/12/2013  01:12 am    <DIR>          .
23/12/2013  01:12 am    <DIR>          ..
05/09/2013  09:46 am            60.319 filesystem.packages
05/09/2013  09:46 am               159 filesystem.packages-remove
05/09/2013  09:45 am     2.410.737.664 filesystem.squashfs
05/09/2013  09:46 am        17.296.271 initrd.img
05/09/2013  09:47 am           176.764 memtest
05/09/2013  09:46 am         2.250.960 vmlinuz
               6 archivos  2.430.522.137 bytes
               2 dirs   1.486.944.256 bytes libres
```

I think that the **filesystem.squashfs** file is the important part here, but I am not sure.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have a look at the file. If your system has squashfs support loaded (`grep squashfs /proc/filesystems`) then mount the file: `losetup /dev/loop0 .../filesystem.squashfs; mount -t squashfs /dev/loop0 /mnt/tmp`

Comment: @HaukeLaging, I have `squashfs` in `/proc/filesystems`, but keeping your instructions I get `/media/temporal2 seems to be mounted read-only` (in fact it is).

Comment: And now you wonder why that is? You can mount the squashfs file but not read-write?

Comment: Yes, @HaukeLaging: I can mount it an cd into any directory, but not write (`mkdir`, for example). I have rebooted and done `mount -o remount,rw /media/temporal2` with same results.

Comment: If you want rw you unsquashfs file.sfs ./ ; chroot ./. If ro is fine mount file.sfs ./ ; chroot ./

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, it seems that **SquashFS is a read-only filesystem**, and writing is not possible into it, so, even when you could **chroot**  into it by installing `squashfs` support, the only way to change the contents is something like [these instructions](http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/paranoid-penguin-customizing-linux-live-cds-part-i) resumed to:

1. Mount the SquashFS and **extract** the contents to a loop device or directory.
2. **Edit** what should be needed (as `chrooting` is possible now) in that loop device or directory.
3. Recreate a **new SquashFS** from the loop device.

As for today, it seems there is nothing more easy.

EDIT: it seems [these other instructions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80305/mounting-a-squashfs-filesystem-in-read-write) are more compact.
EDIT2: no need for a loop device on step 1. You can just `chroot` into the directory of extraction.