# Writing to a readonly partition

Tags: linux, filesystems, boot, partition, squashfs

I have the following situation with which I need some help.

I have a Linux-based OS running on a RaspberryPi Compute Module. The system was shutdown abruptly, which led to an issue where now the boot process keeps looping endlessly. This is because of a systemd service which cannot startup.

My approach to interrupting the endless loop is to try and disable the systemd service from starting up, by mounting the Compute Module and removing the systemd symlink. But here comes my problem:

The system is divided into several partitions, one of which (the root partition) is ReadOnly (squashfs). On this root partition is the `/etc/systemd/system` folder where I want to remove the symlink to the problematic service, so I can disable it.

My question is: How do I go about making changes to this ReadOnly partition so I can disable the systemd service?

Alternatives are also welcomed.

Comment: By remounting it `rw`. See `man mount` for more info

Comment: I have tried `sudo mount -v -o rw,remount -t squashfs /dev/sdb3 /media/user/disk` but it doesn't do anything. The output from `mount` still lists the partition as readonly

Comment: Did you `umount` it first before trying?

Comment: No, I did not. Will try now

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. It looks like this only functions if the partition is already mounted, which was the case the first time I tried. The following is the output I get when trying to remount the unmounted partition:
```
$ sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb3 /media/user/disk/
mount: /media/user/disk: mount point not mounted or bad option.
```

Comment: Drop the `remount` flag, you're trying to mount it new

Comment: Dropped the `remount` flag, and the partition is till mounted as readonly.
/dev/sdb3 on /media/user/disk type squashfs (ro,relatime)

Comment: This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80312/332764) explains how to modify a squashfs image. You could create a new image without the symlink and replace the original image. Then fix the issue, shutdown the system properly and replace the modified image with the original.

Comment: @Freddy the post you gave me unfortunately doesn't 100% fit to my situation. In my case, there is no .squashfs file which has to be modified, it's the squashfs *partition* which is mounted already. Thank you for the suggestion though